# Inertia group $I_K$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar K /K^{nr})$ as a group

Tags: field-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a local field.
Then, elements of $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar K /K)$ which induces identity map on residue field forms group, and the group is called inertia group of $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar K /K)$, and written like $I_K$.

I heard it is known that $I_K$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar K /K^{nr})$ as a group. In other words, **inertia field is maximal unramified extension**. But I couldn't find another reference except for Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves'.

Could you give me self-contained strategy of this isomorphism or references ? (If possible, online accessible one is appreciated)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $K^{nr}$?

Comment: maximal unramified extension of $K$.

Comment: $nr$ for "not ramified"? I'm used to $K^{\rm unr}$  since not ramified$=$unramified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by first proving/recalling the following:

> If $L/K$ is a finite unramified extension then the map $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)\to\operatorname{Gal}(\ell/k)$ is injective (in fact a bijection but we just need the former).

This can be proved by recalling one elementary fact about $L/K$ being finite unramified is that $L=K(a)$ for some element $a\in\mathcal O_L$ for which $\ell=k(\overline a)$ where $\overline a$ is the residue of $a$ in $\ell$. Then the hypothesis $\sigma\in\ker(\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)\to\operatorname{Gal}(\ell/k))$ means that $\sigma(a)\equiv a\mod\mathfrak m_L$, and using uniqueness from Hensel's lemma then you can deduce that $\sigma(a)=a$ so $\sigma=\operatorname{id}_L$.

With this claim proved it is easy to show that $\sigma\in I_K\iff \sigma|_{K^{nr}}=\operatorname{id}$ (you'll want to recall that finite extensions of $k$ correspond to finite unramified extensions of $K$).

Comment: I knew the statement you showed with proof, but I didn't notice the last sentence. Thank you so much. In my understanding, $σ$ which is identity on $K^{nr}$ corresponds to $σ$ which induces $σ^~$ on residue field $k$ is identity, that is, inertia group. But in my understanding, I use objectivity, how did you probed the last sentence with only infectivity?

Comment: I have $\sigma$ is trivial on $K^{nr}$ if and only if $\sigma$ is trivial on $L$ for all $L/K$ finite unramified if and only if (by the mentioned fact) $\sigma$ induces the trivial map on $\ell/k$ for all $\ell/k$ finite if and only if $\sigma$ induces a trivial map on the residue field of $\overline K$.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this (in slightly greater generality) for example in Neukirch, Algebraic Number Theory, Chapter II §9, Proposition 9.11, or in J.S.Milne's lectures notes on [Algebraic Number Theory](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANTc.pdf), Theorem 7.58.